# Change input background without changing default border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background image and color of a `input[type=text]` element but when I change those the border is also changed. 
I would like to have the original (browser dependant) border. In IE it would be thin black, in Webkit it would be very very thin and gray. In other browsers it could be different.

Is there a way to do this in CSS or javascript? I am setting the properties in JS because some calculations are involved. Here is a working minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/nacho4d/k0oxsywp/1/

```
// <input type="text">
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // Some color calculated in js
input.style.backgroundImage = 'Some image I generate in js';
input.style.border = ??? // Restore browser default style.
```

**Note**: In chrome for example the default input border is very very thin and I haven't found a way to reproduce it. In IE it is `border: thin solid black`.

Comment: Can you add MCVE(s) that demonstrates the effect you're describing?

Comment: I think it is not possible to do this with CSS. Since you are already using JS, maybe you could try to get the initial border using `getComputedStyle` and then apply it after adding the background color. (I haven't tried it. Its just an idea).

Comment: i think input for border is 1px solid  and padding is 2px by default just setting them for input text with background will make them look same https://jsfiddle.net/xzgfmkLe/2/

Comment: @Amit I have added a MCVE . Please see the fiddle link added :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should not do this. From my experience you should not put only the defaults and use them the best solution is to set your own rule about the border style, hover, focus and e.t. .

If you want to preserve the default border you should get it before you make the change.

Here is a example how to get it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_border.asp

```
// <input type="text">

var input = document.querySelector('input');
var borderStyle = input.style.border ;
input.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // Some color calculated in js
input.style.backgroundImage = 'Some image I generate in js';
//and then when you change the background or what ever change are set it again
input.style.border = borderStyle;
```

I did not try this approach but in order to preserve the default this should be the algorithm. Again my opinion is to set a default border for all.

Comment: I have tried this. Even with getComputedStyle(input). I get a thicker border :(

Comment: It cannot be thicker then 1 px set it with some defaults.

Comment: If you added a defaults is it working properly?

Comment: What do you mean by *add a default*? Can you show this idea in the fiddle I added?

Comment: See what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/ygoot36o/

Add a style after the initialize it is not a good practice to use the default behavior of elements every browser hove different interpolation of what it need to visualize.